# Element Selector in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

This is a sample **ReactJS** Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    doument.getElementById("my-id1").innerHTML = "Some Text Here"
return (
<div className="App">
    <p id="my-id1"></p>
</div>

);
}
export default App;
```

But while Running the syntax of `document.getElementById()` in **React Native**, I get a runtime error.

What should I use instead of `document.getElementById()` in **React Native** to achieve the exact same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you want to insert text in a html tag. In React props are used to tell the component what properties it will have, sample:

```
const SampleComponent = props => {
   return (<p> {props.text} </p>)
};
```

in your component:

```
return (
     <SampleComponent text = {"Hi world"} />
)
```

**This is a basic pattern in designing a view using React or React native. Note that you must not use HTML in react native, you must use its native analogs (View, Text, TextInput for xample).**

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure what you want to try to do in React Native with that.Can you plz explain maybe I'll be able to help.

`doument.getElementById("my-id1").innerHTML = "Some Text Here"`

is not possible in react native.

You can use `useState()` or `states` in react native to do it.

Let me know if you need more information on that.